# Display posts from another page on home page in wp-editor

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, shortcode, get-posts

I use this code for display posts from another page on home page in `front-page.php` template:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('project')
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="project-item">
                    <?php
                    $overview_image = get_field('small_overview_image');
                    ?>
                    <div class="project-item_img">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $overview_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-item_title">
                        <div class="project-item_title-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

                        <?php
                        global $post;
                        $post = get_post($post_id);

                        $projects_page = get_the_ID();
                        var_dump($projects_page);

                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true

                        );
                        $post = new WP_Query($args);
                        $child_subtitle = get_the_subtitle($post);

                        var_dump($child_subtitle);
                        ?>
                        <div class="project-item_title-description"><?php echo $child_subtitle; ?></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;  endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

But its not good solution, because i use ACF plugin - repeater sections, and posts duplicated in each sections.

Need to add code for display posts in only one section, need to use shortcode and need set limit for posts - 3 item. How can this be done?

Comment: sounds like a great reason to stop using ACF.

Comment: ... and even without the reliance on ACF which probably make the question off-topic, it is just hard to understand what is it you actually ask. how is `wp_editor` is related to this, what is a section and probably more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created shortcode in functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('projects', 'projects_shortcode');
function projects_shortcode($atts){

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        //'caller_get_posts' => 1
    ), $atts));

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => $post_type,
    'post_status'       => $post_status,
    'posts_per_page'    => $posts_per_page
);

global $post;

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
$out = '';
if ($posts->have_posts())
    while ($posts->have_posts()):
        $posts->the_post();

        $overview_image = get_field('small_overview_image');

        $out .= '<div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="' . get_the_title() . '" class="project-item">                    
                <div class="project-item_img"><img class="img-fluid" src="'.$overview_image['url'].'" /></div>
                <div class="project-item_title">
                <div class="project-item_title-name">'.get_the_title().'</div> 
                <div class="project-item_title-description"></div></div>';
        $out .='</a></div>';
    endwhile;
else
    return; // no posts found

wp_reset_query();
return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```

In wp-editor i use shortcode `[projects]`